# Formula to find matching row value based on cells in multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-2010, formula, pivot-table, lookup

I am trying to lookup a col4 value when, in the same row, col1, col2 and col3 each match.

I referenced this [SO Post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDaBP.png) as it is a similar question but that solution is not working for me.

I am searching for specific `Source`s, on specific `Date`s, with specific `Status`s and want to return the corresponding `Count`s.

My data with examples  of output required:

[image: ReuploadedImage]

Comment: Im wondering why we got a downvote on this

Comment: fair enough - i did research first though, im going to post an answer using VBA, the formula solutions I researched online I could not get them to work for my situation

Comment: Yeah I was getting 15 and result didnt make sense.  I actually found much simpler to simply write custom VBA solution - I just assumed there was a simple formula solution.  Btw - I have never used a pivot table might be interesting to see what I could do with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not be preferred approach and might not even give the correct answer but for anyone new to PivotTables the sooner they are comfortable with them the more effort they are likely to save themselves:

[image: SO19433337 example]

Select your dataset (A1:D16 above), Insert > Tables – PivotTable, PivotTable. Choose New Worksheet or, as here, Existing Worksheet Location F1. Drag the fields from the upper box into the smaller boxes as shown. The rest is just formatting, unless complicated by specific requirements for treatment of `Src All`.

Comment: Ill give that a look when I get into work next week, thanks pnuts

Comment: I was looking for a non-programming solution, but a pivot table really makes the most sense based on what I am trying to do so I am going to accept this as the answer although original Q not completely answered (in case others are looking for formula type answer)

Answer (score 4):

To use `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` with multiple lookup fields, you must commit it as an array formula.  Use nested `IF()` statements to select for each criteria.  You have to push CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter a formula as an array formula.

```
=INDEX(col4,
    MATCH(criteria1,
        IF(col2=criteria2,
        IF(col3=criteria3,
    col1
        )), 
    0)
)
```

If you entered it correctly with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, you will see curly braces around the formula `{ }`

Also see [this article from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/59482)