# Identify Rows with Same Values in 2 Different Columns

Tags: excel

I have a data set of roughly 405,000 rows and 23 columns.  I need the records where the value in column "D" is the same as the value in column "H" for that row.

So for

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H 
13 8 21 ok  3  S  - of
51 7 22 no  3  A  k no
24 3 23 by  3  S  * we
24 4 24 we  3  S  ! ok
24 9 25 by  3  S  @ we
75 2 26 ok  3  S  9 ok
```

etc...

I'd get back the 2nd row, the 6th row, etc...

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H 
51 7 22 no  3  A  k no
75 2 26 ok  3  S  9 ok
```

Based on other posts like: [Formula to find matching row value based on cells in multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433337/formula-to-find-matching-row-value-based-on-cells-in-multiple-columns/19433626#19433626) I tried using a Pivot Table, but it complains I can't put either of my two columns in the "Columns" area because there is too much data.  With both columns in the "Rows" area, I get a relationship of D to H, but I can't then find a way to filter on only those where D = H.

I've also looked into countifs(), vlookup, and index / match functions, but I can't figure this out.  Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a simple "IF()" formula in a new column.

For your example add a new column I and use the following formula in the first data row (I2):

```
=IF(D2=H2,"Yes","No")
```

Fill down to the end of the data.

Then using Excel filters or countif you can check the number of "Yes" vs "No" in your data.